# Setting up username and password for npm registry URL

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-registry, npm-config

I am trying to use npm to install a package from url : http://host:80

I did the following:
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry "<>"
npm --proxy http://host:port install <> (our proxy does not require authentication)

When I tired to run above install package command it throws 
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Authorization Required: @latest

When I should I set the username and pwd for registry url.I googled and found that registry url and details are part of .npmrc file.

Currently it has 
strict-ssl=false
registry=<>`enter code here`

Should I add username and password here in this file ? If so can you give me the format or how to add it or where to add it.Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

**If you want to auth to your NPM registry (like Artifactory)**

You can provide the login details as below at runtime

```
npm login
```

Alternatively you can paste following in the .npmrc file.

```
_auth = <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> (converted to base 64)
email = youremail@email.com
always-auth = true
```

If you are getting any SSL issues you can add following to disable SSL

```
strict-ssl=false
```

**If you want to configure proxy settings**

```
npm config set proxy http://"username:mystrongpassword"@proxy.mycompany.com:PORT
npm config set https-proxy http://"username:mystrongpassword"@proxy.mycompany.com:PORT
```

Comment: Also if your password contains any special characters (like @ ) you should URL encode it (https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/). For ex:  password like  test@123   would look like   http://username:test%40123@proxy.mycompany.com:PORT

Answer (score 1):

You can set separate profile(s) for the secondary registry, in your case `http://host:80` using `npmrc` tool.

First install `npmrc` globally on your machine with:

```
npm i npmrc -g
```

Make sure installation went fine, by listing all available profiles:

```
npmrc
```

It should show your `default` profile.

Add a separate profile, so you can customise your registry hostname, with:

```
npmrc -c work
```

where `work` can be any preferable name for your profile.

Select it with:

```
npmrc work
```

Then add your specific hostname with:

```
npm config set registry http://host:80
```

Finally add user with credentials and email, using:

```
npm adduser
```

It will prompt you for all needed data.

To switch back to default profile (with default npm registry), you can use:

```
npmrc default
```