# Need to insert username and password after a command executed in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: npm, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm creating a bitbucket pipeline and after the execution of a npm command I have to provide username and password. Normally in my computer I'm the one entering the username and password typing. How can I accomplish this in the bitbucket pipeline YAML file?

Example:

```
npm install X
```

after that username is asked:

```
Username:
```

Comment: Instead of trying to solve using an interactive script in CI, try getting rid of the interactivity https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624038/5708566

Comment: @windowsill thanks, that is kind of the idea, although, I don't know how to make it work. Should I just add _auth = <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> (converted to base 64) to my .npmrc file and that's it?